# Most efficient way to convert pandas series of integers to strings?

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

Is .astype(str) the most efficient way to convert a series of ints to a series of strings?  It seems rather slow so I wanted to ask.

Comment: This uses an internal routine that is nansafe. But, the null check is pretty cheap, so makes sense to have this take a fastpath (if no nulls). Issue is here:https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8732

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few things and found a faster way using numpy:

```
setup = """
import pandas, numpy
s = pandas.Series(numpy.random.randint(1,10,(100)))
"""

>>> timeit.timeit('s.astype(str)', setup=setup, number=10000)
3.33058500289917
>>> timeit.timeit('s.apply(str)', setup=setup, number=10000)
3.572000026702881
>>> timeit.timeit('s.apply(lambda x: str(x))', setup=setup, number=10000)
3.821247100830078
>>> timeit.timeit('s.values.astype(numpy.str)', setup=setup, number=10000)
0.08432412147521973
```

As you can see, accesing the numpy array with `values` and using the `astype` call is over 40x faster than the next fastest method.